# How to get LatLngBounds of feature polygon geometry in google maps v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a lot of polygonal features loaded with loadGeoJson and I'd like to get the latLngBounds of each.  Do I need to write a function that iterates through every lat long pair in the polygon and does an extend() on a LatLngBounds for each, or is there a better way?  (If not, I can probably figure out how to iterate through the polygon vertices but pointers to an example of that would be welcome)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Polygon-features doesn't have a property that exposes the bounds, you have to calculate it on your own.

Example:

```
   //loadGeoJson  runs asnchronously, listen to the addfeature-event
   google.maps.event.addListener(map.data,'addfeature',function(e){

      //check for a polygon
      if(e.feature.getGeometry().getType()==='Polygon'){

          //initialize the bounds
          var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

          //iterate over the paths
          e.feature.getGeometry().getArray().forEach(function(path){

             //iterate over the points in the path
             path.getArray().forEach(function(latLng){

               //extend the bounds
               bounds.extend(latLng);
             });

          });

          //now use the bounds
          e.feature.setProperty('bounds',bounds);

        }
  });
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/qtDR6/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/qtDR6/)

Comment: This does not apply to MultiPolygon?

Comment: where add more coordinates ? Or modify the coordinates(Lat,Lng) ?

Comment: @manu29.d at v3, the geometry type check is not necessary. Just calling e.feature.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(path) { bounds.extend(path); } ) worked for me on a multipolygon.

Answer (score 16):

In Google Maps JavaScript API v2, Polygon had a getBounds() method, but that doesn’t exist for v3 Polygon. Here’s the solution:

```
if (!google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds) {
    google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds = function () {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        this.getPath().forEach(function (element, index) { bounds.extend(element); });
        return bounds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution for v3 Polygon :

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

map.data.forEach(function(feature){
  if(feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Polygon'){
    feature.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(latlng){
      bounds.extend(latlng);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: How do you implement this? After I use this function can I then call getBounds()? I have no idea what the code is trying to do here or how it helps me.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Dygear/40e6e4770ece73955a267905e1ad8539